# Imprimir un char con println

Tags: java

tengo este código:

```
System.out.println((char)-1);
```

A mi me sale , con -2 con también, con -3 ya cambia a � y con -4 no imprime nada.

Por qué estos resultados?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Qué intentas conseguir?

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido hacer eso, no tiene ningún motivo práctico. Un saludo

Comment: En ese caso [Wymcael](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/77111/wyrncael) te ha dado una respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Cuando haces

```
char a=(char)-1 ;
```

Ocurre un *underflow*: puesto que char va desde 0 hasta 65535, si sobrepasas esos valores se hace una operación *módulo* y se suma el resto.
Por tanto es lo mismo que hacer

```
char a=(char)65535;
```

Por tanto,

```
(char)-4
```

es lo mismo que

```
(char)65532
```

Si no se muestra es porque posiblemente no sea un carácter imprimible o la tipografía usada no contempla ese valor o sí sea imprimible pero no por sí sólo, sino acompañando a algún otro caracter.

Answer (score 1):

La tabla [ASCII](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) va desde el 0 hasta el 255, por lo que si conviertes cualquier número dentro de este rango a `char` no tendrás problemas.

Si te sales de este rango (como es tu caso) no encontrará ningún carácter por lo que te saldrá �.

Estas asignando a `char` números negativos, pero al ser `char` una representación numérica de un carácter esto no es posible, ya que se sale del rango de representación.

Si quieres imprimir un numero negativo por pantalla no es necesario que lo conviertas a `char` pudiendo imprimir directamente `-2`.

Comment: De hecho, char en Java son dos bytes, con lo que va desde 0 hasta 65535. Los valores son Unicode